# Popup View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to figure out how to show a popup view as the images below show in swift. I have seen methods that do this using a separate view controller and that sounds a little longer and perhaps there is a simpler way. If there is a similar question or tutorials that can show how to do it, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking to create a [PopOver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/). As far as I know, the most efficient way to do what you're talking about is by using separate a ViewController like you mentioned, and presenting it as a PopOver. A quick Google search of PopOvers in Swift gives a few tutorials.

You could also manually show a series of views and buttons that lay on top of your first ViewController, but this method is extremely over-complicated and would take much more work to set up.